# Do we have a word for the state of being photogenic?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What's a noun for the state of being photogenic? For instance, if someone says, 'I'm not very photogenic' and I want to counter by saying

> I have to differ with you regarding your __________________________.

'Photogenicness' is a bit awkward. I have not found anything in Webster's Dictionary.

Comment: photogenicity. Noun. (uncountable) The state of being photogenic.

Comment: [Not difficult to find the answer](https://www.google.com/search?q=photogenicity&rlz=1C1ARAB_enBR495BR495&oq=photogenicity&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.5063j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't need the judgement. It's not in Webster's online. Do you have a citation @Centaurus?

Comment: I kinda like _photogenesis._

Comment: I kinda like [*photogeny,*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/263755) but [*photophily*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/264669) certainly has something going for it as a "neologistic" re-usage.

Comment: See the link I provided.

Comment: @dwilli as has been pointed out  by Centaurus, the word is probably  *photogenicity*, but nobody would ever use this word. It sounds like something that has been invented by the speaker - it does not appear in the OED., Iidiomatically, you would say: "I have to differ with you regarding your not being photogenic."

Comment: @Centaurus I also thought of *photogenicity*, but it's not in Merriam-Webster either. And for what it's worth, ELU flags it as a typo. Still, it's a valid answer. It has at least one legitimate dictionary definition.

Answer (score 1):

Two words, but how about **photo friendliness**? Your example:

> I have to differ with you regarding your **photo friendliness**.

It's both eminently useable in a sentence -- written or spoken -- and, if in the latter case you deliver it with a smile, could amuse the recipient as well (depending on the recipient). If spoken, your other party won't know or care whether you're using one word or two. If you really need one written word, no one will stop you if you use **photofriendliness**.

A Google search indicates that makeup is sometimes marketed based on its **photo friendliness**.